# Microsoft IdentityModel Clients ActiveDirectory compatibility with PCL

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I am looking for a resource (link, website, document, another stackoverflow thread etc.) which can tell me how to set up the Portable Class Library targets so that it can be compatible with specific version of NuGet Package of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case whoever stumbling upon same issue, found a good link describing the fix.

http://www.appzinside.com/2016/08/12/installing-adal-nuget-package-for-portable-xamarin-project-causes-an-error/